# Is it possible user account can be a private company?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This [user](https://askubuntu.com/users/305705/trimantra-software-solution), seems to promoting a 'private company', they puts a private company name with their logo in user profile, I don't know is it allowed or not, please let me know is it allowed or not.

Expecting discussion.

Comment: As long as no spam and promotion occur in questions and answers, I don't see any problem with that. Your profile is yours. You can promote whatever you want in it.

Comment: It is possible, but it is not very wise. Haters might come after you, you might scare possible costumers because of poor answers or little reputation. These days these people on this internet hunt everyone down.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

AFAIK anybody can use stackexchange sites, as long as they follow and/or accept site rules and policies.

As far as AU is concerned, **anyone with a Ubuntu question can ask a question**, it may be a person, a group of friends, **It can be a company** or even a government. For the same reason, a user may be a company and therefore **they can promote(in their profile)** and display themselves as who they are, as in case of the aforementioned user.

Not to mention that as [@dan](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11568/is-it-possible-user-account-can-be-a-private-company#comment19788_11568) said, **they should not spam the site** or promote there products in questions/answers/comments etc.

Answer (score 4):

On the same note, a user can also be an intermediate between other non-English users and the site. In my case, almost 50% of all questions I have are from either Indian, Spanish, French or even English friends that because of one reason of another don't know how to create a question with the right words or post the issue in a manner that can get help.

I have helped a little over 100+ New/Old Ubuntu users with this method and this has also helped future visitors with the same questions. A Win-Win if you ask me. So as long as the account is used by following the sites rules and policies, the account will not be closed or issues a warning.